Print sourse ID during liquidsoap transition
the liquidsoap script below is not printing the label of the source after transition, can anyone help with this
#!/usr/bin/liquidsoap
# Log dir
#log.file.path.set("/home/liquidsoap/config/radio.log")
#set("log.level",4)
print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++")


# Activate the telnet server
settings.server.telnet.set(true)
set("server.telnet.port",1234)
set("server.telnet.bind_addr","0.0.0.0")

b = interactive.bool("studio3", false)
a = interactive.bool("alnawawi", false)
v = interactive.float("volume", 1.)
t = interactive.float("threshold", -25.)
t1 = interactive.float("threshold_studio3", -38.)
t2 = interactive.float("threshold_alnawawi", -25.)


primary_source = input.http("http://icecast2:8382/primary.mp3")
secondary_source = input.http("http://icecast2:8382/secondary.mp3")
studio3_source = input.http(id="studio3_source","http://listen.com.au:8382/studio3.mp3")
studio3_source =  gate(studio3_source,threshold = t1,attack = 0.015)

alnawawi_source = input.http(id="alnawawi_source","http://listen.com.au:8382/alnawawi.mp3")
alnawawi_source =  gate(alnawawi_source,threshold = t2,attack = 0.015)

def transition(old,new) =
    print(source.id(old))
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    system("python /home/liquidsoap/config/udp.py")
#    sequence([old,new])
  sequence(merge=true,[
    fade.final(duration=20.,old),
    fade.initial(duration=10.,new)
  ])
end

live_remote=strip_blank(max_blank=120.,input.harbor(id="live_remote","live_remote",port=8383,password="test",icy=true, buffer=5.0, max=10.0))
mic=input.harbor(id="mic","mic",port=8383,user="source", password="test",buffer=2.0)
wavestation=strip_blank(max_blank=120.,input.harbor(id="wavestation","wavestation",port=8383,password="test",icy=true, buffer=5.0, max=10.0))

backup_playlist = playlist(mode="normal",id="myplaylist","/home/liquidsoap/content/music.m3u")

radio = fallback(track_sensitive=false, [live_remote,wavestation,strip_blank(max_blank=120.,primary_source),strip_blank(max_blank=120.,secondary_source),backup_playlist])

radio = switch(track_sensitive=false,transitions=[transition,transition],[(b,studio3_source), (a,alnawawi_source), ({true},radio)])
radio = smooth_add(p=0.15, normal=radio, special=strip_blank(max_blank=2.,mic))

radio = amplify(v, radio)
radio = nrj(radio)
radio =  gate(radio,threshold = t,attack = 0.015)
radio = filter.iir.butterworth.bandpass(frequency1 = 25.0,frequency2 = 14000.0, order = 4, radio)
radio = sky(radio)
radio = server.rms(radio, id="radio_source")


# Stream it out
output.icecast(fallible=true, %mp3(bitrate=80), host = "icecast2", port = 8382, password = "test", mount = "main_test.mp3", radio)


Unfortunately can't tell why it's not working, but this is what I used to identify the currently active source. I put it right before the output. Maybe it helps as a workaround.
def print_current_source(metadata)
    print("Livestream current source")
    print(string(radio.selected()))
    if string(radio.selected()) == "<source#input.harbor>" then
        print("input.harbor is supposedly active")
    end
end
radio.on_track(print_current_source)


Thanks, i get the following error, mind if you share your script...or help print(string(radio.selected()))
Error 5: this value has no method selected
